# Async and await in nodejs (Web Api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, express

I am trying to use promise in my loop but the loop doesn't wait but prints an empty array value which is declared above. Here is my code:

node:

```
let total_json = [];
     await Promise.all(results.map(async (element) => {
                if (element.start_date <= d && element.end_date >= d) {
                  let query = "select * from tb_voucher_category where id = " + "'" + element.cateID + "'";
                  body.query = query;
                  COMMON(body, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) { fatal_error.data = err; return res.json(fatal_error); }
                    if (results) {
                      if (results.length > 0) {
                        cate = results[0].cateName;
                      } else {
                        cate = "";
                      }
                      let json = {
                        id: element.id,
                        catename: cate,
                        title: element.title,
                        description: element.description,
                        expired_date: element.expired_date,
                        expired_time: element.expired_time,
                        vStatus: element.vStatus

                      }
                     total_json.push(json);
                    }
                  });
                }
              }));

    ///i need the json printed here but it becomes null. how can i use async or promise here?
    console.log(total_json)
```

i have seen lots of stack question, I just couldn't implement  it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in your COMMON function. in the below example you can easily figure out what the issue is. why it prints an empty array because of the callback function.

```js
 let total_json = [];
        let results = [
          { catName: "cat", id: "1", title: "title", description: "desc", cateID: "2" }
        ];
        results.map(element => {
          let body = { query: "" };
          let query =
            "select * from tb_voucher_category where id = " +
            "'" +
            element.cateID +
            "'";
          body.query = query;
          COMMON(body, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              fatal_error.data = err;
              return res.json(fatal_error);
            }
            if (results) {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                cate = results[0].cateName;
              } else {
                cate = "";
              }
              let json = {
                id: element.id,
                catename: cate,
                title: element.title,
                description: element.description
              };
              total_json.push(json);
            }
          });
        });
    
        function COMMON(data, func) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            func(null, [{ catName: "cat" }]);
          });
        }
    
        console.log(total_json);
```

so I just add Promise.all to resolve this issue & I set element as a parameter in the COMMON function  and return it from callback as newElement

```js
 let total_json = [];
    let results = [
      { catName: "cat", id: "1", title: "title", description: "desc", cateID: "2" },
      {
        catName: "cat2",
        id: "10",
        title: "title2",
        description: "desc2",
        cateID: "20"
      }
    ];
    results.forEach(element => {
      let body = { query: "" };
      let query =
        "select * from tb_voucher_category where id = " +
        "'" +
        element.cateID +
        "'";
      body.query = query;
      total_json.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          COMMON(body, element, (err, results, newElement) => {
           
            if (err) {
              fatal_error.data = err;
              return res.json(fatal_error);
            }
            if (results) {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                cate = results[0].cateName;
              } else {
                cate = "";
              }
              let json = {
                id: element.id,
                catename: cate,
                title: element.title,
                description: element.description
              };
              resolve(json);
            }
          });
        })
      );
    });
    
    function COMMON(data, element, func) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        func(null, [{ cateName: "cat" }], element);
      });
    }
    
    Promise.all(total_json).then(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Express.js (inferred from `res.json()`), I suggest to isolate the database calls from the response.

```js
function resultsToJSON(results) {
  if (results.length > 0) {
    cate = results[0].cateName;
  } else {
    cate = "";
  }
  let json = {
    id: element.id,
    catename: cate,
    title: element.title,
    description: element.description
  };
  return json;
}


// returns a single promise that resolves to a list of json results,
// or rejects as an error.
function getData() {

// `promises` is a list of Promises that either resolve to the database result,
// or rejects due to a database error.
const promises = results
  .filter(element => element.start_date <= d && element.end_date >= d)
  .map(element => {
    let query = "select * from tb_voucher_category where id = " + "'" + element.cateID + "'";
    body.query = query;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       COMMON(body, (err, results) => {
         if (err) { reject(err); }
         else { resolve(results); }
       });
    });
  });

return Promise.all(promises);

}
```

Then, in your Express request handler, you can handle the error (and send the error response), or get the `total_jsons` array from resolving the Promise.

```js
// mark function as `async` if you are going to use `await` in the body.
app.get("/yourAPI", async (req, res) => {

  // given that `getData()` returns a promise that resolves to a list of results,
  // `await getData()` waits for the promise to be resolved, and returns the list of results.
  try {
    const total_json = await getData();
  } catch (error) {
    // handle a failure in *any* of your database requests
    fatal_error.data = error;
    res.json(fatal_error);
  }
});
```